# find chromatic number

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, graph-connectivity

I came across this problem in my textbook.(problem no: 3)
[image]

I created a graph with students as vertices and if two students took same course,then there is an edge between them.
But I ended up getting this graph
[image]

I'm not sure how to proceed further.

Comment: Well, let me start by asking: why is the title of your post "find chromatic number"?

Comment: @diracdeltafunk This is one of the exercise problems for the chromatic numbers chapter

Comment: So, how do you expect chromatic numbers to help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want to interpret the question as one about the chromatic number of a graph. This means that you assign colours to vertices. Here, colours should be time slots (whose number you want to minimize), and the vertices have to be things that  get assigned a time slot, i.e., rhe vertices are the courses. Also, edges shall represent obstacles to assigning the same time slot (=colour) to distinct courses (=vertices). Hence we join courses by edges whenever they have a student in common. So e.g. Linda gives rise to an edge $AT$, and Abe gives rise to three edges $CF$, $CT$, and $FT$.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense. Chromatic numbers comes out to be 4.